# Simulating lag function on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get lagged values (current row - last row) from the following table:

```
+-------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| index | codigowine | preconormal | timestamp           |
+-------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
|     2 | 10088      |       65.60 | 2014-11-18 23:39:08 |
|  1005 | 10088      |       62.60 | 2014-11-20 11:00:14 |
|  2028 | 10088      |       62.60 | 2014-11-21 09:00:13 |
|  3092 | 10088      |       62.60 | 2014-11-22 09:00:12 |
|  5083 | 10088      |       69.00 | 2014-11-24 09:00:13 |
+-------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

The expected output should be:

```
+-------+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+
| index | codigowine | preconormal | timestamp           | lag_price |
+-------+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+
|     2 | 10088      |       65.60 | 2014-11-18 23:39:08 |      0.00 |
|  1005 | 10088      |       62.60 | 2014-11-20 11:00:14 |     -3.00 |
|  2028 | 10088      |       62.60 | 2014-11-21 09:00:13 |      0.00 |
|  3092 | 10088      |       62.60 | 2014-11-22 09:00:12 |      0.00 |
|  5083 | 10088      |       69.00 | 2014-11-24 09:00:13 |      6.40 |
+-------+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

I've seen some examples emulating the lag function on MySQL by setting a variable and calculating the difference between rows, but I just can't get it to work:

```
SET @price=0;
select index,codigowine,@price price_lag, @price:=preconormal curr_price from precos order by codigowine, timestamp;
```

Here's a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/966a1/1/0).

Other possibilities would be to calculate using php or adding a new table and doing the programming via python, but I'm trying to avoid these possibilities if I'm able to perform this through SQL.

Comment: just put `preconormal - @price as lag_price` into the field list BEFORE you do the `@price :=` update. MySQL processes variables and variable assignments left->right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some more digging, and the suggestion by @Marc B, I finally got to where I wanted. In case anyone else needs help, here's my answer:

```
set @price = (select preconormal from precos where codigowine='10088' order by timestamp asc limit 1);
```

On the line above I'm setting @price to the first record instead of zero, to avoid getting a lag_price of 65.60 on the first row.

Below is the actual result:

```
select codigowine, preconormal - @price as lag_price, @price:=preconormal curr_price from precos WHERE codigowine='10088' order by timestamp;
```

Here's [the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/966a1/13/1) working.